# How to handle managed event(c#) in managed C++

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c++-cli

We have an application that is written in managed C++(C++/CLI) which is using another library which is written in C#. An event will be raised from managed code and we want to handle that event in managed C++ code.

**Managed C# Code for Event**

```
using System;

namespace CSharpWithEvent
{

    public class UpdateInfo
    {
        public string PropertyName { get; set; }
        public int NewValue { get; set; }
    }

    public class ValueChangeEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        private UpdateInfo _updatePacket;

        public UpdateInfo UpdatePacket
        {
            get { return _updatePacket; }
            set { _updatePacket = value; }
        }
        public ValueChangeEventArgs(UpdateInfo updatePacket)
        {
            _updatePacket = updatePacket;
        }
    }
    public class ImageManager
    {
        private EventHandler<ValueChangeEventArgs> _onValueChanged;
        public event EventHandler<ValueChangeEventArgs> OnValueChanged
        {
            add { _onValueChanged += value; }
            remove { _onValueChanged -= value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method that is called to update Image.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="updatePacket"></param>
        public void UpdateImage(UpdateInfo updatePacket)
        {
            /*Raised Event*/
            if (_onValueChanged != null)
            {
                _onValueChanged(this, new ValueChangeEventArgs(updatePacket));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Code for ImageUserClass.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vcclr.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace System;
using namespace CSharpWithEvent;

class ImageUserClass
{
public:
    gcroot<ImageManager^> m_imageManager;
    ImageUserClass();
    void OnImageValueChange(Object^ sender, ValueChangeEventArgs^ updatePacket);
};
```

**Code for Handler in Managed .cpp file**

```
#include "stdafx.h";
#include "ImageUserClass.h";

ImageUserClass::ImageUserClass()
{
    m_imageManager = gcnew ImageManager();
    m_imageManager->OnValueChanged += gcnew EventHandler<ValueChangeEventArgs^>(this, &ImageUserClass::OnImageValueChange);
}
void ImageUserClass::OnImageValueChange(Object^ sender, ValueChangeEventArgs^ updatePacket)
{
    //TODO: Make necessary changes.
}
```

I have implemented and tried to handle that event but I am getting following error.

Error   1   error C3364: 'System::EventHandler' : invalid argument for delegate constructor; delegate target needs to be a pointer to a member function

Please help me to solve above issue

Comment: It is convinced that ExcelJsonShare::OnCellChanged is not a member function of the ExcelJsonShare class.  I am too, it resembles the name of the event too much.

Comment: @Hans Passant. This function is member function of ExcelJsonShare class, this class is written in managed c++.

Comment: I have modified it and given different name but still same problem.

Comment: If you don't post your code then you can't get any help.

Comment: Please find more information about it and let me know if any more information is required for same.

Comment: Did you just tell Hans to find more information about your 2 word problem? I'm looking at it, you're not even using **the same member name**! Voting to close.

Comment: The ImageManager class does not have an OnValueChanged() method.  Change the 1st argument to the delegate constructor from *m_imageManager* to *this*.

Comment: @Blindy : I meant to ask Hans to find more information that I had added in my post and so asked to check them. Yes, I made some mistakes in same and so apologize for same.

Comment: Now added actual file contents which I am using and when compiled will throw exact error that is in question.

Please take consideration of above and guide for what should be done to handle this error.

Thanks, in advance,,, :)